# Style input type file?

Tags: html, css, file, input, cross-browser

Is it possible to style a input element of type file without worrying about browser compatibility? In my case I need to implement a background image and round border(1px), the button should also be customised if possible.

Answer (score 30):

Follow these steps then you can create custom styles for your file upload form:

1.) This is the simple HTML form(please read the HTML comments I have written here bellow)

```
    <form action="#type your action here" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="yourBtn" style="height: 50px; width: 100px;border: 1px dashed #BBB; cursor:pointer;" onclick="getFile()">Click to upload!</div>
    <!-- this is your file input tag, so i hide it!-->
    <div style='height: 0px;width: 0px; overflow:hidden;'><input id="upfile" type="file" value="upload"/></div>
    <!-- here you can have file submit button or you can write a simple script to upload the file automatically-->
    <input type="submit" value='submit' >
    </form>
```

2.) Then use this simple script to pass the click event to file input tag.

```
    function getFile(){
        document.getElementById("upfile").click();
    }
```

Now you can use any type of a styling without worrying how to change default styles.
I know this very well, because I have been trying to change the default styles for month and a half. believe me it's very hard because different browsers have different upload input tag. So use this one to build your custom file upload forms.Here is the full AUTOMATED UPLOAD code.

```
<html>
<style>
#yourBtn{
   position: relative;
   top: 150px;
   font-family: calibri;
   width: 150px;
   padding: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px dashed #BBB; 
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #DDD;
   cursor:pointer;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getFile(){
   document.getElementById("upfile").click();
 }
 function sub(obj){
    var file = obj.value;
    var fileName = file.split("\\");
    document.getElementById("yourBtn").innerHTML = fileName[fileName.length-1];
    document.myForm.submit();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
</script>
<body>
<center>
<form action="#type your action here" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm">
<div id="yourBtn" onclick="getFile()">click to upload a file</div>
<!-- this is your file input tag, so i hide it!-->
<!-- i used the onchange event to fire the form submission-->
<div style='height: 0px; width: 0px;overflow:hidden;'><input id="upfile" type="file" value="upload" onchange="sub(this)"/></div>
<!-- here you can have file submit button or you can write a simple script to upload the file automatically-->
<!-- <input type="submit" value='submit' > -->
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice solution. Use 'display:none' on the input instead of 'height: 0px; width: 0px;overflow:hidden;'  to remove it from the DOM/your layout as well.

Answer (score 8):

Same solution via Jquery. Works if you have more than one file input in the page.

```
$j(".filebutton").click(function() {
    var input = $j(this).next().find('input');
    input.click();
});

$j(".fileinput").change(function(){

    var file = $j(this).val();
    var fileName = file.split("\\");
    var pai =$j(this).parent().parent().prev();
    pai.html(fileName[fileName.length-1]);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: could you post a fiddle for that?

Answer (score 3):

After looking around on Google for a long time, trying out several solutions, both CSS, JavaScript and JQuery, i found that most of them were using an Image as the button. Some of them were hard to use, but i did manage to piece together something that ended out working out for me.

The important parts for me was:

- The Browse button had to be a Button (not an image).
- The button had to have a hover effect (to make it look nice).
- The Width of both the Text and the button had to be easy to adjust.
- The solution had to work in IE8, FF, Chrome and Safari.

This is the solution i came up with. And hope it can be of use to others as well.

Change the width of .file_input_textbox to change the width of the textbox.

Change the width of both .file_input_div, .file_input_button and .file_input_button_hover to change the width of the button. You might need to tweak a bit on the positions also. I never figured out why...

To test this solution, make a new html file and paste the content into it.

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

.file_input_textbox {height:25px;width:200px;float:left; }
.file_input_div     {position: relative;width:80px;height:26px;overflow: hidden; }
.file_input_button  {width: 80px;position:absolute;top:0px;
                     border:1px solid #F0F0EE;padding:2px 8px 2px 8px; font-weight:bold; height:25px; margin:0px; margin-right:5px; }
.file_input_button_hover{width:80px;position:absolute;top:0px;
                     border:1px solid #0A246A; background-color:#B2BBD0;padding:2px 8px 2px 8px; height:25px; margin:0px; font-weight:bold; margin-right:5px; }
.file_input_hidden  {font-size:45px;position:absolute;right:0px;top:0px;cursor:pointer;
                     opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);-ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=0)";-khtml-opacity:0;-moz-opacity:0; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="fileName" class="file_input_textbox" readonly="readonly">
 <div class="file_input_div">
  <input id="fileInputButton" type="button" value="Browse" class="file_input_button" />
  <input type="file" class="file_input_hidden" 
      onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName').value = this.value" 
      onmouseover="document.getElementById('fileInputButton').className='file_input_button_hover';"
      onmouseout="document.getElementById('fileInputButton').className='file_input_button';" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a fiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/gd4wuvga/

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple css only solution, that creates a consistent target area, and lets you style your faux elements however you like.

The basic idea is this:

1. Have two "fake" elements (a text input/link) as siblings to your real file input. Absolutely position them so they're exactly on top of your target area.
2. Wrap your file input with a div. Set overflow to hidden (so the file input doesn't spill out), and make it exactly the size that you want your target area to be.
3. Set opacity to 0 on the file input so it's hidden but still clickable. Give it a large font size so the you can click on all portions of the target area.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwwar/nFLKU/

```
<form>
    <input id="faux" type="text" placeholder="Upload a file from your computer" />
    <a href="#" id="browse">Browse </a>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <input id="input" size="100" type="file" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the clip property along with opacity, z-index, absolute positioning, and some browser filters to place the file input over the desired button:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets/Clipping

Answer (score 0):

use `uniform js plugin` to style input of any type, select, textarea.

The URL is 
http://uniformjs.com/