# What CSS can I use to make an HTML file field transparent?

Tags: html, css

I want to have an `<input type='file'>` that overlaps on an image, so that when the user clicks on it, the file upload dialog opens, and the image uploads via AJAX.

So I want CSS to style the field in such a way that either only the browse button is visible (with no associated box), or even better, only a transparent button is visible with overlapping text like "change photo", nothing else.

Needs to work on:

- FF 3+
- IE 7+ (pref 6+)
- Chrome 5+
- Safari 3+
- Opera 9+

Comment: How would a transparent button be visible? Kind of an oxymoron there.

Comment: You should use something like http://www.plupload.com/ instead.

Comment: duplicate of [Style input type file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909228/style-input-type-file) and many other questions.

Comment: @Aron: not really. The question you linked to is about styling file fields generally, whereas this one is about making them partially or completely invisible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File input opacity test => http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/LVjFy/ ..set its opacity to 0 and it's fully transparent but clickable!

Another example with img and transparent file input => http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/LVjFy/2/

**EDIT** (+ js that simulates the file input click): http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/LVjFy/6/  ..don't need to set opacity (**EDIT2** needs to be tested, isn't working on FF)

Comment: @Web Developer in ff (3.6.13) both mine and your solutions are working good ;) ...btw in FF you *must* click inside the input (text part) not outside of it, and to achieve this you could *drive* the user by adding a label between the input (z-index 2) and the image (z-index 0).. check it out http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/LVjFy/8/ (tested on FF)

Comment: thanks now works awesome. although i like my solution (coz i developed it) i have selected your as the answer as most of the image is clickable

Comment: All three links in the answer are now broken.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t fancy your chances. `<input type="file">` isn’t generally very style-able, because CSS can’t really describe its layout.

Answer (score 0):

the magic word is "opacity".

```
input /* type="file" */
{
opacity:0.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE 7 */

}
```

You can click it, but dont see it ;)

Answer (score 0):

My solution http://www.jsfiddle.net/dHFyZ/

Answer (score -1):

`background: transparent` should do the trick for any invisible element that you want clickable.