# Opacity input file on ie7, ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Well, i got this code:

```
<div class="teste">
    <input type="file" name="teste" />
    teste
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.teste {
   width:300px;
   height:100px;
   position:absolute;
   top:10px;
   right:10px;
   overflow:hidden;
   background-color:#FF0000;
   opacity:1; 
   filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

input[type=file] {
   position:absolute;
   top:0px;
   right:0px;
   font-size:300px;
   opacity:0;
   filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

In FF and Chrome works perfect but in ie the text 'teste' get white i figured out that when input file over the text 'teste' it get white.

someone knows how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: I reedited your answer fixing some typo. now it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/LCpR9/

Answer (score 10):

I was very intrigued to why that solution is not working on IE7 / IE6, so, up to install windows XP (comes with IE6) and test the Fiddle!

**First I've tested this:** <sup>should work as stated [here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990679/what-css-can-i-use-to-make-an-html-file-field-transparent)</sup>

[See the Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/kHM32/)

```
<div class="teste">
    <input type="file" name="teste" />
    teste
</div>

.teste {
   width:300px;
   height:100px;
   position:absolute;
   top:10px;
   right:10px;
   overflow:hidden;
   background-color:#FF0000;
   opacity:1;
   filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

input[type=file] {
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
}
```

---

And it didn't work, so, **realizing that the browser is old as hell**<sup>[MS IE css support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sup>, I've removed the `input[type=file]` and replaced it with a plain old class 
`.the_file`. The end result was a complete success in solving the OP's problem:

See the [Fiddle with](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/kHM32/2/) the TESTED solution!

```
<div class="teste">
    <input type="file" name="teste" class="the_file" />
    teste
</div>

.teste {
   width:300px;
   height:100px;
   position:absolute;
   top:10px;
   right:10px;
   overflow:hidden;
   background-color:#FF0000;
   opacity:1;
   filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

.the_file {
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
}
```

### Final Notes:

This was tested on *Windows XP Professional v2002 SP2* with **IE6 v.6.0.2900.2180**, afterwards updated and tested with **IE7 v.7.0.5730.13**.

On IE7, both solutions work!

---

**UPDATE:**

Tested now also in: <sup>under same winXP</sup>

- IE 8 v8.0.6001.18702
- Opera 11.64
- K-Meleon 1.5.4
- FF 3.6.16
- Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m
- Safari 5.1.2 (7534.52.7)
- IE 9 v9.0.8112.16421IC <sup>under win7</sup>

---

Also noticed that you were mentioning the text getting white! Not happened on any of the tests performed!