# How to make input file look in the same style as standard jQuery UI input?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I've created standard UI input looking in the same way as jQuery UI combobox/autocomplete. But how to do the same with input file?

http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/KWZwQ/

There are a lot of [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909228/style-input-type-file) questions on the SO, but I need a solution with jQuery UI.

Comment: What do you mean "a solution with jQuery UI" ? Check the duplicates you posted, you can achieve this with CSS/CSS3 and jQuery. You're loading the jQuery library anyway if you're using UI. I guess you want to write less code?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is for jquery ui -> [Jquery ui file style](https://github.com/ManuDavila/jquery-ui-file-style)