# customize file upload

Tags: html, file-upload, customization

I want to customize the input="file" as follow: 
1. the user will click on large image instead of the classic button "Browse"
2. Immediatly after choosing the file it's will submit the form, so the user not having to submit another botton, (I want to catch the event "open" on the choose file dialog"

I'll appreciate any help

I tried the solution offer here:
[How to customize <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813344/how-to-customize-html-input-type-file)

but this isn't working in IE, also in chrome when you click the image, where it's not above the hidden button - it's not working.

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There are no features in HTML that can customise a file input, So the technique is to absolutely position the input tag over whichever element you'd like to use setting `opacity=0`, you could then add the `onClick="$("#submit-button").click()"` to the element (omitting the usual `return false`). I've never manually implemented this technique before but can imagine that the form may post before the file is ready in which case you may need to use the `setTimeout( fn )` function to give the browser enough time to figure itself out (be sure to test with files of all sizes).

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909228/style-input-type-file) post gives some extra details, personally I use a JQuery plugin [Javanto/JQuery-fileinput](https://github.com/javanto/jquery-fileinput) which "replaces" (using the technique above) the input with whatever content you specify.

Answer (score 0):

This is my fully functional customerized file upload/Attachment using jquery & javascript (Visual studio). This will be useful !

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).mousemove(function () {
        $('#myList').css('display', 'block');
        $("#seebtn").css('display', 'none');
        $("#hidebtn").css('display', 'none');
        $('#displayFileNames').html('');
        $("#myList").html('');
        var fileArray1 = document.getElementsByClassName('file-input');
        for (var i = 0; i < fileArray1.length; i++) {
            var files = fileArray1[i].files;
            for (var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
                $("#myList").append("<li style='color:black'>" + files[j].name + "</li>");
            }
        };

        if (($("#myList").html()) != '') {
            $('#unselect').css('display', 'block');
            $('#divforfile').css('color', 'green');
            $('#attach').css('color', 'green');
            $('#displayFileNames').html($("#myList").children().length + ' ' + 'files selezionato');

        };

        if (($("#myList").html()) == '') {
            $('#divforfile').css('color', 'black');
            $('#attach').css('color', 'black');
            $('#displayFileNames').append('Nessun File Selezionato');
        };
    });

  });

  function choosefiles(obj) {
        $(obj).hide();
        $('#myList').css('display', 'none');
        $('#hidebtn').css('display', 'none');
        $("#seebtn").css('display', 'none');
        $('#unselect').css('display', 'none');
        $("#upload-form").append("<input class='file-input inputs' type='file' onclick='choosefiles(this)' name='file[]' multiple='multiple' />");
        $('#displayFileNames').html('');
    }

  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#unselect').click(function () {
            $('#hidebtn').css('display', 'none');
            $("#seebtn").css('display', 'none');
            $('#displayFileNames').html('');
            $("#myList").html('');
            $('#myFileInput').val('');
            document.getElementById('upload-form').reset();         
            $('#unselect').css('display', 'none');
            $('#divforfile').css('color', 'black');
            $('#attach').css('color', 'black');

        });
    });

</script>
```

```css
<style>
  .divs {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    .inputs {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        height: 5%;
        width: 5%;
        opacity: 0;
        background: #00f;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .icons {
        position: absolute;
    }

 </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <div>
                <form id='upload-form' action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                   
                    <div class="divs" id="divforfile" style="color:black">
                        <input id='myFileInput' class='file-input inputs' type='file' name='file[]' onclick="choosefiles(this)" multiple='multiple' />
                        <i class="material-icons" id="attach" style="font-size:21px;color:black">attach_file</i><label>Allegati</label>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <br />
            </div>
            <br />  
            <div>
                <button style="border:none; background-color:white; color:black; display:none" id="seebtn"><p>Files &#9660;</p></button>
                <button style="border:none; background-color:white; color:black; display:none" id="hidebtn"><p>Files &#9650;</p></button>
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" id="unselect" style="display:none;float:left">
                    <span style="color:red">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <div id="displayFileNames">
                </div>
                <ul id="myList"></ul>
            </div>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Code will be available at the comment section !

Link : https://youtu.be/It38OzMAeig

Enjoy :)