# HTML5: How to specify the width of a file input?

Tags: css, html

The W3C validator says: "Attribute size not allowed on element input at this point."

```
<input type="file" name="foo" size="40" />
```

What is the correct way to specify the width of a file input in HTML5?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909228/style-input-type-file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the input field use the style attribute, this allow you to use css.

`<input type="file" name="foo" style="width: 40px" />`

Or with separate css:

```
input[name="foo"] {
  width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Firefox ignores the "width" property. That was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Ahh of course. Then I think you should support the width property and the size for cross browser compatibility. Or try workarounds suggested in link posted by @Sirko.

Comment: If you come up with an answer to your problem please let me know :)

Comment: `width` also works on Firefox nowadays.

Answer (score 7):

In your css file, specify the width as such:

```
input[type=file] { width: 300px; border: 2px solid red; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VbTAV/

Comment: I'm on Firefox, and in your example, it's actually the "size" attribute that controls the width (even though it's not allowed), and not the "width" property. I tried changing "width" in your example to 200 or 400, and it has no effect.

Comment: True. The size attribute seems the way to handle Firefox, for now.

Comment: `width` also works on Firefox nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended in the other answers, the `width` of the *entire* file input, i.e. button *and* filename text, can be set using CSS as follows:

```css
input[type="file"] {
  /* functional */
  width: 100%;
  /* cosmetic */
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

(This also works in Firefox nowadays.)

*However*, this does *not* change the width of the file select ***button***. This may cause problems such as clipping, as illustrated in the following snippet.

```css
input[type="file"] {
  width: 40px;      
}
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

To modify the file select ***button*** width (and/or other button styling), you can use the [::file-selector-button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button) pseudo element. For example:

```css
input[type="file"] {
  width: 40px;
}

input:last-of-type::file-selector-button {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


/* cosmetic */

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 8px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file">
<input type="file">
```

Comment: This doesn't quite do what you describe. On Firefox the 2nd and 3rd code examples show the width covering the whole input (button and file name area) rather than just the button. The button should be a child of the file input in CSS.

Comment: @martin Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you clarify? Perhaps my description is not sufficiently clear: The second code example should show a clipped button without filename area. The third example should show a complete button without filename area. Afaik the button is an intrinsic part of the file input, hence the need for the special selector.

Comment: No, the third example shows "Bro...." on Firefox.

Comment: @Martin Yes, that's intentional. By "complete button" I meant the button element, including rounded corners, etc. The default button text does not fit, so it is clipped, with ellipsis, as specified in the example's `text-overflow`.

Comment: In the second example the entire button is clipped, cutting the border, etc. In the third example only the button text is clipped. Anyway, this is just an illustration. The intended message is: If you need to style the file selector button, which is part of the file input, you need to use `::file-selector-button`.

Comment: @Martin I modified the third example for convenient comparison of the cases with and without the `::file-selector-button`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the 'input' inside a div:

```
  <div style="width: 40%">
     <input class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center" style="background-color: yellow; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; width: 100%" type="file" id="file"/>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<form  class="upload-form">
    <input class="upload-file" data-max-size="2048" type="file" >
    <input type=submit>
</form>
<script>
$(function(){
    var fileInput = $('.upload-file');
    var maxSize = fileInput.data('max-size');
    $('.upload-form').submit(function(e){
        if(fileInput.get(0).files.length){
            var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
            if(fileSize>maxSize){
                alert('file size is more then' + maxSize + ' bytes');
                return false;
            }else{
                alert('file size is correct- '+fileSize+' bytes');
            }
        }else{
            alert('choose file, please');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9bhcB/2/