# Custom CSS/HTML Browse For Image Form

Tags: php, html, css, forms, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Style input type file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909228/style-input-type-file)

I know that each browser has its own way of displaying a...

```
 <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="input_text"/>
```

My question is, is there a way to customize the browse for image button. I would like to replace the browse and upload buttons on the normal form to one image button using HTML/CSS/PHP. Is this possible and is it compatible with all browser types.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways, the way I prefer is this:

```
<div class="browse">
    <div class="placeholder">Upload</div>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="input_text"/>
</div>
```

With this CSS-code:

```
.browse {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}

.browse input, browse div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.browse input {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

This way the upload text will be shown but you will actually click the browse button.

Comment: Yes but instead of their being a button that says "Choose File" I would like to replace that with and image that does that.

Comment: Then replace: <div class="placeholder">Upload</div> with: <div class="placeholder"><img src="yourimagefile" /></div>

Comment: ok that worked thank you one more question though. After I browse and choose my file does that submit the form?

Comment: No, you can put an onchange event on the input if you'd like to? Just replace: <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="input_text"/> with <input onchange="this.parentNode.parentNode.submit();" type="file" name="image" id="image" class="input_text"/>

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off using a plugin like ***[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)***. It'll allow you to style the field like any other element.