# How to style a input type=file in html?

Tags: javascript, css, html, file-upload

I did some research and found it could be hard to style a input type=file. However, I realized youtube has a beautiful button displayed when you want to upload your video to the site. (may need login: http://www.youtube.com/upload).

so basically it allows user to click the button, pick a file, and do the upload. 
I am not sure how this is implemented instead of using the ugly `<input>` tag? Or anyone knows any alter good way to make a beautiful file upload interface?

Comment: see:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909228/style-input-type-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909228/style-input-type-file

Comment: @Sudhir I have already read those threads, but those are for a input field, I am asking for a upload button only (with out a text field) please refer to the youtube link I posted. The threads you shared does not solve my problem

Comment: @dTDesign Google did not solve my problem. I know there is a workaround to set the real file input to be opacity = 0 and put a fake one on top of it to fake the style, but that is not my problem. I want a single button to upload a file.

Comment: Check This out buddy, it may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16491593/2261259

Comment: @AllanJiang: But why? There is a working solution and you want another?

Comment: @dTDesign Shankri has provided a great solution. A traditional solution is have the file input opacity =0 and overlay on top of a good style input, but that does not solve my question because I just want a button with out any text field. Shankri's solution is make the file input opacity = 0 and have another button click event call it. I prefer this solution better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ehEqUGU/2/edit)

```
<button id="imageDrop" onclick="document.getElementById('uploadImage').click()" title="Click or Drag Image">Upload image</button>

<input id="uploadImage" type="file" />
```

```
#imageDrop{      
  background:#fff;
  width:300px;
  height:180px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-style:italic;
  border-radius:18px;
  border:2px dashed #444;
}

#uploadImage{
  visibility: hidden;
  height:0px;
  width: 0px;
}
```