# Correcting formatting of <input type="file"> in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, input-type-file

The markup is a simple `<input type="file" class="uploadImageInput"></input>`

Please help me vertically center the "No file chosen" text. I have tried all that I could, vertical-align etc. See screenshot below:

[image: Rendering on Chrome (bad)]

Btw, Firefox seems to render the desired result as shown below. Need help for Chrome please. It would be such a shame to go through the route suggested by quirksmode (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html), as my requirement is very basic. Thanks.

[image: Rendering on Firefox (good)]
EDIT/UPDATE: Turns out that the problem was with the `line-height:1.625` declaration in  `<body>` which got inherited to this `input`. Forcing `line-height:1` for this `input` solved it. But is strange that Chrome and Firefox deal with this so differently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Style input type file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909228/style-input-type-file)

Comment: I cannot see it as a duplicate as I am seeking a solution, that does not involve javascript, for a simple requirement. The other question starts off with javascript and has solutions / kludges full of javascript/jquery/faux images etc.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should look at this link: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/27/css-form-elements-problem/ especialy the paragraph about file input and the selector I did not knew before:  `input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button`

This link refers to an older article: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200701/styling_form_controls_with_css_revisited/ (sligtly outdated, but gives a good idea of the differences between browsers)

Comment: Thanks for the useful links. I went through them. But my problem was different and I got the solution by isolating this field and applying all styles affecting it one by one.