# Style file input

Tags: html, css, file-io

I want to update this file input to look like the image I've attached.

Currently I have this view:

> http://davis-design.de/marktadresse/mein-profil.html

But I would like it to look like the following:

[image]

My current attempt:

```
 <span class="btn">
     <span class="fileupload-new">Bild auswählen</span>
     <span class="fileupload-exists">Ändern</span>
     <input type="file" name="bild" id="bild">
 </span>
```

How would I go about styling the default file input element?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909228/style-input-type-file

Comment: Oh Nice question thread. Thx. I don't see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a word of warning from past experience, certain methods of styling a file upload doesn't always work cross browser, and has given me some gray hair. But I believe the below solution should work for most cases

Based on the answer from @BjarkeCK

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9182787/1105314

**Fiddle**

> http://jsfiddle.net/D9T4p/1/

**Markup**

```
<div style="padding:100px;">
    <div class="uploadButton">
        BILD AUSWÄHLEN
        <input type="file" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $(".uploadButton").mousemove(function(e) {
        var offL, offR, inpStart
        offL = $(this).offset().left;
        offT = $(this).offset().top;
        aaa= $(this).find("input").width();
        $(this).find("input").css({
            left:e.pageX-aaa-30,
            top:e.pageY-offT-10
        })
    }); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
.uploadButton input[type="file"] {
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    opacity:0;
}

.uploadButton {    

   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
   cursor:pointer;

/*** (Copied from the link you supplied) ***/
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 13px;
   font-family: 'Roboto',Arial,sans-serif;
   padding: 8px 22px;
   display: inline-block;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
   box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
   color: #FFF;
   background-color: #2561BA;
}
```

**Update**
CSS only solution:

> http://geniuscarrier.com/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-button-in-pure-css/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jqtransform here to customize your input type here

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy css-only solution. you don't need any javascript for it. so - just dont.

The keyword of the solution is: `<label>`.

Label? - Yes a label! 
The simple HTML Element. You can easily style an `<label>` element.

Here is a sample:

### HTML

```
<label for"foo"></label>
<input type="file" id="foo"/>
```

### CSS

```
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#foo {
    height: 0.1px;
    width: 0.1px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

You dont use the input element itself. You'll use the label instead. If you click on the label, you'll get referenced to the 'real' input element and its functionality.