# HTML file input, name in the input

Tags: html, input, filenames

I'm working on an upload option, now I'm working on the lay-out of my file input. What I want to make is an input where the filename changes with the *browse* of the file input.

**Code Now**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label><input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
  <input class="btn btn-success btn-block uploadform" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**What I get now**

https://scrshot.eu/s/4a157f9.png

**What I want to get**

https://scrshot.eu/s/b73c306.png
- It has to be still clickable

Does somebody has an idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: clear your question...

Comment: You can look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909228/style-input-type-file

Comment: @Bunyomayn I've found that page before, couldn't find the answer to my question there.

Comment: Where are you declaring the BROWSE?

Comment: @The_Monster it's the file input. (See first link in begin post)

Comment: Isn't the default behaviour of the file input to show the name of the selected file?

Comment: @DavidJones Yes i also tought that its the default behavior

Comment: @DavidJones Yes, but I want it not next to it, I want to let the 'Browser' part change to the name of the file.

Comment: @DevNiels so the button text will change to the name of the file?

Comment: @DavidJones I'm trying to do that yes.

Comment: @DevNiels Seem like a lot of effort for something so small.You first task would be too look reading the filename from the upload. See this article http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, thank you all

```
data-filename-placement="inside"
```